# What makes this mnemonic device work for multiplication?

Tags: mnemonic

I stumbled across a mnemonic device related to multiplication, outlined on this wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table#Patterns_in_the_tables). I see that it does work, but I'd like to know why. It works as follows (from the wikipedia page):

```
         →                 →
       1 2 3             2   4
    ↑  4 5 6 ↓         ↑       ↓
       7 8 9             6   8
         ←                 ←
         0                 0
      Fig. 1             Fig. 2
```

> Figure 1 is used for multiples of 1, 3, 7, and 9. Figure 2 is used for
>   the multiples of 2, 4, 6, and 8. For example, to memorize all the
>   multiples of 7:
>
> 1. Look at the 7 in the first picture and follow the arrow.
> 2. The next number in the direction of the arrow is 4. So think of the next number after 7 that ends with 4, which is 14.
> 3. The next number in the direction of the arrow is 1. So think of the next number after 14 that ends with 1, which is 21.
> 4. After coming to the top of this column, start with the bottom of the next column, and travel in the same direction. The number is 8. So
>      think of the next number after 21 that ends with 8, which is 28.
> 5. Proceed in the same way until the last number, 3, which corresponds to 63.
> 6. Next, use the 0 at the bottom. It corresponds to 70.
> 7. Then, start again with the 7. This time it will correspond to 77.
> 8. Continue like this.
>
> These patterns can be used to memorize the multiples of any number
>   from 0 to 10, except 5. As you would start on the number you are
>   multiplying, when you multiply by 0, you stay on 0 (0 is external and
>   so the arrows have no effect on 0, otherwise 0 is used as a link to
>   create a perpetual cycle).

In the interest of further clarification: you choose a figure to use by looking for your number in a corner position. If, for example, you wanted the multiples of 8:

1. Start at the bottom right corner of Fig 2, and follow the arrow left to the 6
2. Thus, the next multiple of 8 is the next number that ends in '6', so 16.
3. Then move to the rightmost position of the upper row and you see that your next multiple end in a '4', so it's going to be 24. Etc.

I imagine similar devices could be constructed for numeric systems with bases other than ten, and I bet it'd be interesting to understand what's going on here. Does anyone have any insight into this? Is this something that falls under the umbrella of Number Theory?

Comment: Is Fig. 2 used anywhere?

Comment: @TrevorWilson - yes, it is. I added another example to explain it further. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $7$, note that the number above is always $3$ less than the number below.  When you add $7$ to a number, you can also add $10-3$.  For $9$, the number to the left is $1$ less and you are adding $10-1$.  The evens work similarly.